# setting cookie.domain in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Trying to set a domain in the cookie in asp.net and I am very novice in asp.net so wanted to know how this can be done.

here is my code

```
// Create cookie
var cookieData = new NameValueCollection();
cookieData["first_name"] = first_name;
cookieData["last_name"] = last_name;

var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("UserInfo", cookieData);
cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
//cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
cookie.Domain = "example.com";
cookie.Path = "/";
```

Need to set the cookie to work for srv1.example.com & srv2.example.com

currently running through Visual Studio and using Request.RequestURI.Host gives me the domain as localhost.

Comment: c# it is why what's wrong

Comment: That's not how you get a cookie's domain. Google it.

Comment: I used google before coming here because i did not find definitive answers on google

Comment: @user1833222 Just unclear when you say "currently running through Visual Basic"

Comment: yeh running it locally

Comment: @user1833222 Visual Studio you mean

Comment: Updated OP's question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ASP.NET page that is setting this cookie was requested from `http://localhost` meaning that you are running your application either in Visual Studio or the local IIS, you cannot set the `domain` property to something different than that.

But if you deploy your application on a different server and access it from `example.com` then the domain property of the cookie will be correctly set.

Comment: right but then why is it showing me localhost when i check the cookies in firefox

Comment: you are right I am running the code through Visual Basic running IIS locallly, so you are saying with the current code I have and setting the domain to example.com on production it should take the appropriate domain and sent the cookie correctly with the appropriate domain

Comment: I have updated my answer. Actually you cannot set the cookie domain to be different than the currently requested domain.

Comment: so what are you saying  Darin

Comment: If you deploy your application to production and request this page from `http://example.com` or `http://subdomain.example.com` then the domain property of the cookie will be correctly set to `example.com`. So what I am saying is that your code is fine.

Comment: cookie domains are automatically set by the server; no need to assign a value